# Python Code(Code is regarding runing SVM on a file and generating output file with labels) to exe

Tags: python, exe

I have my code ready for SVM classification in python.

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import time 
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now().time()

os.chdir('C:/Users/ShaliniBinayKumar/Desktop/Dataset/')
data_train =pd.read_csv('Train.csv',encoding='latin-1')
data_test = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',encoding='latin-1')

data_train['description'] = data_train['description'].str.lower()
data_test['description'] = data_test['Description'].str.lower()

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words="english")), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',  penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42)),])
clf = text_clf.fit(All_rows[0:len(data_train)], data_train['Category'])
predicted = clf.predict(All_rows[len(data_train):len(All_rows)])
data_test['Pred_Col'] = pd.Series(predicted)
data_test.to_csv('Prediction_SVM_15000_new.csv', index = False)
```

This python code reads two files from a fixed location and generates the output file.

I have to give this code to someone who should run the code without looking at the code. I converted this windows .exe file using below steps:

1. Installed Python 3.6 and `cx_Freeze`.
2. To install `cx_Freeze`, open your command prompt and type `pip install cx_Freeze`. Make a .py program of yourself say `my_first_prog.py`.
3. Create a new python file named `setup.py` on the current directory of your script.
4. On the `setup.py`, code this and save it.
5. With shift pressed right click on the same directory, so you are able to open a command prompt window.
6. Type in the prompt as `>> python setup.py build`
7. Check the newly created folder `build`. It has another folder in it. Within that folder you can able to find your application as .exe.

When i run this .exe is not generating output file and the black screen goes in a second.

Comment: Why won't you run the .exe from a command prompt (Windows Key-R) and see what it is complaining about?

Comment: I ran.exe in CMD, its giving error : SyntaxError:Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file SVMclassifier.exe on line 1 but no encoding declared.                               But same python code when i run in python console,its running. Helpless :(

Comment: Try declaring the encoding at the beginning of the file (according to PEP-263):
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Good thing is error went, but output file still not generated :( black screen opened for a second and went. No file i could see at specified location.

Comment: What does it print in command line? (IMHO you really should have provided this information as [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upvote my previous command since it has proven useful)

Comment: Nothing it prints.simply open a black screen and goes.

Comment: Is `Prediction_SVM_15000_new.csv` created (updated)?

Comment: No,that is the problem "Prediction_SVM_15000_new.csv" is not getting created, after black screen come and goes (without any error).

Comment: The only additional help I can offer is to add logging / debug print messages and see where it gets stuck. Good luck!

Comment: This sounds like the problems I'd have when I'd use pylab or just about any matplotlib when I'd make an .exe My guess is DLL files from sklearn are not being copied into your frozen application. Your solution may be the same as what I used here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872064/scipy-signal-crashes-application-made-with-cx-freeze/46597712#46597712